# "I think she didn't notice" vs "I don't think she noticed"

Tags: grammar, difference

Is it grammatically wrong to say the first phrase?
I've always used the first phrase and today someone told me that it is grammatically incorrect so now I'm questioning my way of speaking.

Comment: Is that someone a grammar expert? Why do you think that he or she might be correct? Do you understand the sentence's structure, or is there something about it that is confusing you?

Comment: No, the grammar is FINE. But the two are somewhat different. Just translate them into your own language, you'll see.

Comment: Both correct, but with different meanings

Answer (score 1):

Both are grammatically correct, but they mean different things. Putting "not" in different places changes what it's negating.

"I think she didn't notice" = "I think (¬ (she noticed))"

"I don't think she noticed" = "¬(I think (she noticed))"

In practice, people often use the second version when they actually mean the first, so the first can sound weird even when that's what one means.

Comment: I don't think they do mean different things. _Think_ is a [Neg-raising](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_raising) predicate, so that your first structure surfaces as the second.

Comment: If I heard one or the other sentence, I would have different opinions how likely it is that she didn't notice. The first is a slightly stronger belief.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's correct. "I think she didn't notice" means the exact same thing as "I don't think she noticed". As a formal English speaker, usually I hear "I think she didn't notice", as it sounds more casual.